# How can I manage to install packages within python-dev on windows systems just like that on Linux?

Tags: python, windows, pip

Actually, we can simply install python-dev on linux just use the following command:

sudo apt-get install python-dev

since python is integrated with Linux. But no such luck on windows. For input "pip install python-dev", there is no corresponding package on pypi.python.org.
What packages should I install to match those when installed by "apt-get install python-dev" command under Linux on Windows?

Comment: does just installing Python2.7 win32 not work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python-dev installs the headers and libraries for linux, allowing you to write / compile extensions.

In windows, the standard installer provides this by default.  The header files are in the $installroot\include directory.  The link libraries are found in $installroot\libs.

For example I've installed python 2.7 into c:\python27.  This means my include files are located here: c:\python27\include.  And the link libraries are in c:\python27\libs

Comment: Thank you, jaime. According to your answer, I have nothing to do with python-dev. That's a good news. In fact, I own three legal copies of Windows, unlike those "free" users. I write codes and know that's laborious work.